# Previous data showing even though cleaning up in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a component in my react native app that loads sessions related to a particular individual. In the `useEffect()` of that component I both load the sessions when the component comes into focus, and unload those sessions within the cleanup.

```
export const ClientScreen = (props) => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const client = useSelector((state) => selectActiveClient(state));
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) {
      const loadSessions = async () => {
        if (client?.id) {
          dispatch(await loadClientSessions(client?.id));
        }
        return () => dispatch(unloadSessions()); // Cleaning up here...
      };
      loadSessions(props);
    }
  }, [isFocused, client?.id]);

  const updatedProps = {
    ...props,
    client,
  };

  return <ClientBottomTabNavigator {...updatedProps} />;
};
```

Generally the component is working as expected. However, I do notice that if I load the component with one client, then navigate away, and then come back to the component by loading a new client, that for a brief moment the sessions pertaining to the previous client show before being replaced the sessions relevant to the new client.

My question is, shouldn't the `unloadVisits()` that runs on cleanup -- which sets sessions to an empty array -- prevent this? Or is this some kind of react behavior that's holding onto the previous state of the component? How can I ensure this behavior doesn't occur?

Comment: Your effect doesn't clean up anything. `loadSessions(props)`  returns a cleanup function, but you simply ignore it. Your effect does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cleanup function` should appear before the closing-brace of the `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isFocused) {
    const loadSessions = async () => {
      if (client?.id) {
        dispatch(await loadClientSessions(client?.id));
      }
    };
    loadSessions(props);
  }

  return () => dispatch(unloadSessions()); // Cleaning up here... // <--- here
}, [isFocused, client?.id]);
```

Comment: This may call `unloadSessions` without ever calling `loadSessions`

Comment: Yes, thanks, this occurred to me as I was writing the question. That it should be outside of the `if` block. Testing now.

Answer (score 1):

as commented, <s>your `loadSessions` returns a cleanup function</s>, but you don't do anything with it. And the effect where you call `loadSessions(props)` does not return anything, that's why it does not clean up.

**Edit:**

I made a mistake, `loadSessions` returns a **Promise** of a cleanup function. And it is impossible to "unwrap" this Promise and get to the cleanup function itself in a way that you can return it in your effect. You have to move the cleaup function out of the `async function loadSessions`.

But you don't need `async/await` for everything:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (isFocused && client?.id) {
    loadClientSessions(client.id).then(dispatch);

    return () => dispatch(unloadSessions());
  }
}, [isFocused, client?.id]);
```

Comment: Will this guarantee that unloadSessions runs before the component becomes unfocused, or should the cleanup be outside the conditional block?

Comment: Also, loadClientSessions() returns a promise, so my understanding is that one should use the implementation I used within useEffect(). If your understanding is that this is not the case, please clarify as to why.

Comment: @Muirik "unloadSessions runs before the component becomes unfocused" I'm not sure what that means. The effect will react on `isFocused` changing its value, but it can't act before it does that.

Comment: @Muirik "loadClientSessions() returns a promise, so my understanding is that one should use the implementation I used within useEffect()" yes, if you always do what you're told without questioning or thinking for yourself. `async/await` is generally encouraged because it makes many things easier and let's us write simpler code. But here; It is impossible to return a cleanup function from an async function. An async function can only return a Promise, nothing else. And you can not call a Promise, because it is not a function. In this case `promise.then()` is simpler than `async/await`